# Why 'onClick' in react got bound to emptyFunction?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why onClick in react get bounds to emptyFunction?

I have next string in my component, it doesn't work:

```
onClick={ me => me.preventDefault() }
```

At the same time, if I change `onClick` to `onMouseDown` - it works.

There are no errors in console. Exploring the DOM gives that onClick handler is emptyFunction from react.

Comment: what means "it doesn't work"?

Comment: also... your component... is a custom component?

Comment: What are you clicking and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: Doesn't work means event is passed to emptyFunction instead fo calling my function. 
And yes, this is custom component

Comment: The same from me. onClick does not have any effect, but changing it to onMouseDown somehow works.

Comment: `onMouseDown` worked for me as well - would be curious to know why.

Answer (score 0):

My previous findings was wrong. 
The real problem was that component had been destructed before the event was handled. This may happen if prevent event propagation somewhere else, especially on body. Or it may happen if there is a handler subscribed to the same event and destruct the component.